# Getting "too many redirects" when using wp_redirect for attachment page

Tags: attachments, wp-redirect

Code comes from the codex:

```
<?php wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post->post_parent )); exit; ?>
```

I added the above, in an empty attachment.php page. When I visit an attachment page (eg. http://example.com/?attachment_id=2071) I get the error:

"This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Why?

UPDATE:

Based on the answer given, I updated my code to:

```
if($post->post_parent != 0):
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->post_parent));
else:
    wp_redirect(get_permalink(2));
endif;
exit;
```

That way if the post_parent == 0, it will go back to the home page. I don't know if I should be catching for anything else. But this seems to work.

Thanks Ignat B. for explaining what was going on. I have a few attachments that have post_parent = 0. And it just happened that the link I was trying out was one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types), and [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) - attachments stores as post records.

Your code is making a loop redirection to the same page. The most reasonable case is:

Your `$post->post_parent` equal to `0`. If you'll make a `var_dump(get_permalink($post->post_parent));`, youll notice that the output would be the same page url.

Comment: Shouldn't media attachments never have post_parent = 0?